# How to throw exception from restful webservice to spring controller?

Tags: java

Actually i am new with restful webservice with exception handling , so anyone can help me by sending about , How to throw exception from restful webservice to spring controller ?

Comment: `restful webservice` created using what..??

Comment: created with Jersey API , like below code of client class that call to the webservice ..

Comment: Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/pyd-bs-webapp/DataSetupUploadFileWS/uploadToFile");
    System.out.println("target.getUri() = " + target.getUri());
    Response wsresponse = target.request().buildPost(Entity.entity(uploadFileCustomerDueDataServiceInput,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();
    System.out.println(wsresponse.getStatus());
    
     output = wsresponse.readEntity(UploadFileCustomerDueDataServiceOutput.class);
    System.out.println("Output ::::::::::::"+"\t"+output.isOutput());